# How to get device supported zoom level for maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

so i am using google maps for flutter, and when i set the zoom level to 18 it zooms to the maximum zoom available, which is not what i want, so i browsed their documentation and i saw

> The supported zoom level range depends on the map data and device.
> Values beyond the supported range are allowed, but on applying them to
> a map they will be silently clamped to the supported range.

from here : https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/CameraPosition/zoom.html

```
await Future.delayed(1.seconds, () async {
           mapController.moveCamera(
           CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
           target: provider.currentPosition!,
           zoom: 18,
        )));
  });
setState(() {});
```

above is the piece of code that does the zooming, it is done in the onMapCreated argument of flutter google maps.

***So my question is, is there a way to check the maximum zoom available to a device so i can set the zoom level correctly.***

Comment: In the android and ios sdk there are methods for capturing the maximum zoom level supported in the coordinates. Check if methods are present in flutter. [android getmaxzoomlevel](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#public-final-float-getmaxzoomlevel), [iOS minZoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view?hl=pt-br);

Comment: hi, thank you, but i am using flutter, do you know how i can get this in flutter?.